# Using ContractNamespace for namespacing enums in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces, wsdl

I am struggling to generate correct WSDL namespaces for my C# enums using `ContractNamespace` instead of decorating each type with attributes.

The following code correctly generates the `Person` type in "http://www.mynamespace.co.za/", but for some reason `Gender` is in a different WSDL namespace, "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeOtherNamespace".

What am I missing? Do enums require special treatment?

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://www.mynamespace.co.za/", ClrNamespace = "SomeOtherNamespace")]

namespace SomeOtherNamespace
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Gender
    { 
        Male,
        Female,
        Other
    }
}
```

In my actual code, the types live in an external, generated assembly. The types cannot easily be decorated with custom attributes. `ContractNamespace` would be perfect if it can work for enums too...

In other words, the following works, but would be extremely painful to get into the code generation process.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.mynamespace.co.za/")]
public enum Gender
{ 
    [EnumMember]
    Male,
    [EnumMember]
    Female,
    [EnumMember]
    Other
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links may help you

- [How to: Import Custom WSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734711(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [WCF Extensibility – WSDL Import (and Code Generation) Extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/10/18/wcf-extensibility-wsdl-import-and-code-generation-extensions.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I will try IWsdlExportExtension

Answer (score 6):

Enums are a pain.  You must decorate the enum for the `ContractNamespace` attribute to take effect.

```
[DataContract]
public enum Gender
{ 
    [EnumMember]
    Male,
    [EnumMember]
    Female,
    [EnumMember]
    Other
}
```

Should see that your type appears in the WSDL namespace you want.